# Execution failed for task ':expo-modules-core:compileDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, react-native, build.gradle

I need to find a solution and an explanation for this error. Thursday it was working and building correctly and the next day I get this error. I don't understand why.

Before I didn't have the kotlin version configured in android/build.gradle but with each version, I get a different error. Please help.

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = '29.0.3'
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 31
    targetSdkVersion = 30
    //kotlin_version = '1.4.20'
}
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.8'
    classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0')
    //classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.4.20")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Someone posted an answer that helped me immensely, but he/she deleted it. Thank you very much anyway.

A new issue was created in the react-native project by Facebook for this situation, in the following link explains the solutions depending of the version.

[Solution](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/35210)

In my case, I had the "react-native" version: "0.64.3," and I updated it to "react-native": "0.64.4".